# Third law of motion when action and reaction are separated by some time

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, causality

For every action there is an equal and opposite reaction. I have used this law only when bodies are in contact with each other which means for every action reaction is produced at same instant of time. What will happen if bodies are separated by a finite distance such that reaction to every action is separated by some time? Will I be able to apply third law of motion in the same way as I was applying when bodies were in contact?

Comment: Not in the same way, you would have to include the fields that cause the delay between the action and reaction forces of the bodies into your calculation. Some people then falsely say that this invalidates the third law, but that's basically just a legal copout using the fact that the third law, as formulated, doesn't include these fields. It's also bad physics because the third law is, technically, a limited version of momentum conservation. The latter is, of course, not violated by setups that use e.g. electromagnetic fields.

Comment: If two bodies are separated, then "something" must be carrying the momentum to transfer from one to the other.  One billiard ball moving freely has no "action" occurring until it contacts another ball, at which point the action-reaction step happens. Fields aside, the second ball is not involved until contact.

Comment: I do not think we should close this question. This is a pitfall that is often not properly explained in introductory physics courses leaving people unsatisfied and confused (leading them perhaps to wrong conclusions). The previous comments have not gotten many upvotes for no reason.